# SELECT where no commissions

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables.

1. account_receivables
2. commissions

`account_receivables` has many commissions

`commissions` has a foreign key towards `account_receivables_id`.

The way my application works is when `account_receivables` gets an insert it also calculates commissions for a group of sales reps, based on `account_receivables.amount`.

There were 2 months where it randomly missed 1 sales rep. So what I am try to do is find out all the `account_receivables.id` where commissions were missed.

Is there a straight SQL query for this? It is a Laravel app and I have tried the below with no luck:

```
$comms = DB::connection('mysqllocal')->table('commissions')
        ->select('account_receivables_id')
        ->whereNotIn('rep_group_number', [999999])
        ->groupBy('account_receivables_id')->get();
```

`999999` being rep_group_number

Comment: Where do you record calculated values?

Comment: From your explanation you are trying to find `account_receivables_id` for which there is NO records in `commissions`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for all records from `account_receivables` that do not have a corresponding record in `commissions`.

A simple `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE ... IS NULL` should do it.

```
select ar.id
from account_receivables ar
left join commissions c on c.account_receivables_id = ar.id
where c.id is null
```

You did not give the full table structure in your question ; the above query assumes that the relation between both tables is as follows (adapt it if needed) :

```
commissions.account_receivables_id -> account_receivables.id
```

Comment: what i have now in commissions table is`code` c.account_receivables_id, c.amount, c.rep_id. I need to find out c.account_receivables_id where rep_id 999999 is not present.

Comment: just so you know, there are many other commissions with same c.account_receivables_id. When account_receivables record is created it might calculate 5 commission records all with same c.account_receivables_id but with different c.rep_id